# Lines in the background of FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am using `FloatingActionButton` for api 21+ its showing perfectly ok but if i look it in api 20- then it has four lines in the background.

Below is the xml code of my `FloatingActionButton`

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_ok"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp" />
```

**The screen for api 21+**

[image]

**The screen for api 20-**

[image]

Just look at the four thick lines below the `FloatingActionButton` in the second screen and give me a solution for removing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for my own question just change the height and width to `wrap_content` and the problem is solved.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/bt_ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
    app:borderWidth="0dp" />
```